# program to find maximum of three numbers (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Program to find the maximum of three numbers:

```
def maximum(a, b, c) :
    if a > b and a > c:
        return a
    elif b > a and b > c:
        return b
    else:
        return c

a = input("ENTER 1st NUMBER\n")
b = input("ENTER 2nd NUMBER\n")
c = input("ENTER 3rd NUMBER\n")
print(maximum(a, b, c))
```

When I input `10`, `11` and `2`, it gives me 2 as output. What is wrong?

Comment: when i input 10 11 and 2 it gives me 2 as output ?

Comment: lol use max(a,b,c)

Comment: without using max()function

Comment: Are your inputs coerced to ints or are you using strings?

Comment: input read as a string so your comparisons are using lexicographic order.

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest to use `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: Mithout using the `max` function? Then you can use `sorted([a, b, c])[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `max` function you can sort the numbers and then return the last one:

```
def maximum(a,b,c):
    return sorted([a,b,c])[-1]

a=int(input("ENTER 1st NUMBER\n"))
b=int(input("ENTER 2nd NUMBER\n"))
c=int(input("ENTER THIRD NUMBER\n"))
print(maximum(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that most answers mentioning `max()` do not provide the logic, so I took the time to write the following code:

```
def max_of_three_numbers(a, b, c):
    return max(a, b, c)

def main():
    a = int(input("ENTER 1st NUMBER\n"))
    b = int(input("ENTER 2nd NUMBER\n"))
    c = int(input("ENTER THIRD NUMBER\n"))

    print(f'\nThe maximum of the numbers is {max_of_three_numbers(a, b, c)}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use `max()` function:

```
print(max(a, b, c))
```

Or if you want to make without `max()` function your code could be simplified to:

```
def maximum(a, b, c):
   if a > b and a > c:
       return a
   elif b > c:
       return b
   else:
       return c
```